# Cannot update game after enabling "App signing by Google Play"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

In order to migrate my app from .apk to .aab I went through the App Signing process that Google Play requires.

I installed Java jdk-14.0.2.jdk (because I purchased a new mac with OS 10.15.5 and it kept saying I don't have Java) and ran the below command from the terminal in the directory that I downloaded pepk.jar from Google Play to

```
$ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=user.keystore --alias=bball\ battle --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a52912392761fb833b656cd48b9de6a
```

Then I uploaded the resulting file `encrypted_private_key_path` so now I can see all of my app signing info under the App Signing section in the dashbaord.

Then I selected my `user.keystore` in unity publishing settings, put in my password, and built the aab file. But when I uploaded it to google play I got a message:

> “You uploaded a debuggable APK or
> Android App Bundle. For security
> reasons you need to disable debugging
> before it can be published in Google
> Play.nullLearn more about debuggable
> APKs or Android App Bundlesnull.”

So then instead of using `user.keystore` I renamed `encrypted_private_key_path` to `encrypted_private_key_path.keystore` and selected that in Unity player settings. But when I select it in publishing settings, it says

> "Unable to list keys in the keystore.
> Please make sure the location and
> password of the keystore is correct."

I know I am using the correct password.

Could this be because Unity is using OpenJDK, but I ran the pepk.jar command using Java jdk-14.0.2.jdk?

Does anyone know how to resolve or troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are supposed to use Java NDK to build the aab the process is pretty much simple im providing a link of a youtube video can check that but make sure to uncheck the development build and check android app bundle box
https://youtu.be/j0L3SDYyMJI
And for the key if the key isnt working you can contact google that you lost the key and i guess you can generate a new one